# View function description in eclim

Tags: vim, eclim

I know if you do the autocompletion you can view the description of the function you are selecting...

Is there any way to view the description in the same way but without autocompleting, just selecting the function over the cursor position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That preview window is populated by Eclim (using Eclipse) on the fly during completion but Eclim doesn't provide any user-level command to get that info outside of the context of completion.

In order to show the signature of the function under the cursor:

- `<C-w>}` opens the tag under your cursor in the preview window
- `:ptag foo` tag `foo` in the preview window

This feature depend on the availability of a `tags` file.

See `:help preview-window` and `:help tag-preview` for some related commands.

Comment: For instance with str_replace I get this output doing what you suggested: "Tags unavailable: E433: No tags file."  While if I write str_ and then do autocomplete I can see the description of str_replace function

Comment: Did you read my answer and the relevant `help` enties? ***"This feature depend on the availability of a tags file."***

Comment: Sorry for delaying my response romaini: I did, but I don't understand it.. I talking about viewing function description in ECLIM, in a default way.

Comment: That preview window is populated by Eclim (using Eclipse) on the fly during completion but Eclim doesn't provide any user-level command to get that info outside of the context of completion. You *can* show the signature of the function under the cursor with the method in my answer but it's a process completely separated from Eclim that requires a tags file and some setup. If I were you I would send a feature request to Eclim's maintainer.